# Flash messanger in zf2

Tags: session, zend-framework2

How can i use flash messenger in zend freamwork 2? Session documentation is not yet. Anyone know it? But session libraries are there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i have written a post about this some time ago. You can find it [right here](http://samminds.com/2012/08/flashmessenger-in-zend-framework-2/)

Basically you use it just the same like earlier.

```
<?php
public function commentAction()
{
    // ... display Form
    // ... validate the Form
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // try-catch passing data to database

        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Thank you for your comment!');

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog-details'); //id, blabla
    }
}

public function detailsAction()
{
    // Grab the Blog with given ID
    // Grab all Comments for this blog
    // Assign the view Variables

    return array(
        'blog' => $blog,
        'comments' => $comments,
        'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages()
    );
}
```

Then in your .phtml file you do it like this:

```
// details.phtml
<?php if(count($flashMessages)) : ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($flashMessages as $msg) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $msg; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously this isn't all too handy, as you have to do this for every single .phtml file. Therefore doing it within the layout you have to do it at best like the following:

```
<?php
// layout.phtml
// First get the viewmodel and all its children (ie the actions viewmodel)
$children = $this->viewModel()
                 ->getCurrent()
                 ->getChildren();

$ourView  = $children[0];

if (isset($ourView->flashMessages) && count($ourView->flashMessages)) : ?>
<ul class="flashMessages">
    <?php foreach ($ourView->flashMessages as $fMessage) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $fMessage; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you need further description, please see my blog, but i guess the code itself is pretty clear (apart frmo the layout.phtml example). Alternatively you're always free to write your own view helper to have it look a little cleaner inside your view-templates.

Comment: I found it quite handy to create a View helper that can access and display the messages. For those that are interested this can be done by implementing ServiceManagerAwareInterface then grabbing FlashMessenger from the ControllerPluginManager which can be accessed via the ServiceLocator. This removes the need to pass the messages from action to the view model each time.

Comment: If you have it at present, how about sharing your code? :) I'm sure this would help out lots of people unfamiliar with it. I just listed the basic work behind the "magic" helpers ;)

Answer (score 15):

**Update :**

Zend Framework new release added FlashMessenger View Helper , found in path `/library/Zend/View/Helper/FlashMessenger.php`

[FlashMessenger.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FlashMessenger.php)

---

**Old answer :**

I have written a custom view helper, for printing flash messages

In /module/Application/Module.php

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(                    
        'factories' => array(                                               
            'flashMessage' => function($sm) {      

                 $flashmessenger = $sm->getServiceLocator()
                                      ->get('ControllerPluginManager')
                                      ->get('flashmessenger');                                   

                 $message    = new \My\View\Helper\FlashMessages( ) ;
                 $message->setFlashMessenger( $flashmessenger );

                 return $message ;
               } 
           ),
    );
}
```

Create a custom view helper in /library/My/View/Helper/FlashMessages.php

```
namespace My\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class FlashMessages extends AbstractHelper
{

        protected $flashMessenger;

        public function setFlashMessenger( $flashMessenger )
        {
                $this->flashMessenger = $flashMessenger ;
        }


        public function __invoke( )
        {

                 $namespaces = array( 
                     'error' ,'success', 
                     'info','warning' 
                 );

                 // messages as string
                 $messageString = '';

                 foreach ( $namespaces as $ns ) {

                        $this->flashMessenger->setNamespace( $ns );

                        $messages = array_merge(
                                 $this->flashMessenger->getMessages(),
                                 $this->flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages()
                        );


                        if ( ! $messages ) continue;

                        $messageString .= "<div class='$ns'>"
                                        . implode( '<br />', $messages )
                                    .'</div>';
                }

                return $messageString ;
        }
}
```

then simple call from layout.phtml , or your view.phtml

```
echo $this->flashMessage();
```

Let me show example of controller action

```
public function testFlashAction()
{
          //set flash message
          $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('warning')
                 ->addMessage('Mail sending failed!');

          //set flash message
          $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('success')
                 ->addMessage('Data added successfully');

          // redirect to home page 
          return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/');
}
```

In home page, it prints

```
<div class="success">Data added successfully</div>
<div class="warning">Mail sending failed!</div>
```

Hope this will helps !

Answer (score 3):

How to grab Flashmessenger’s messages in a View Helper – sharing code as requested by Sam.

The View helper should implement the ServiceManagerAwareInterface interface and related methods. The plugin will now have access to a Service Manager which we can use to get the Service Locator and ultimately access to the Flash Messenger.

I’ve not touched this code since I initially wrote it – so there may be a more elegant way of doing this.

```
protected function getMessages()
{
    $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceManager()->getServiceLocator();
    $plugin = $serviceLocator->get('ControllerPluginManager');
    $flashMessenger = $plugin->get('flashmessenger');

    $messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();

    // Check for any recently added messages
    if ($flashMessenger->hasCurrentMessages())
    {
        $messages += $flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages();
        $flashMessenger->clearCurrentMessages();
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

And calling getMessages() from within the plugin should return an array of messages that can be passed to a partial and rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Add code below to the view to render error messages:

```
<?php echo $this->flashmessenger()
    ->setMessageOpenFormat('<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul%s><li>')
    ->setMessageCloseString('</li></ul></div>')
    ->render('error')
; ?>
```

In previous request, make sure you created an error message by running code below in your controller:

```
$this->flashmessenger()->addErrorMessage('Whops, something went wrong...');
```